# seeing C# windows forms project code from F#

Tags: c#, f#, winforms

I have a C# Windows Forms project open with some C# code in it.

**Question: How can I have an F# file that I can write F# code in but still referencing all the C# code I have on Form1.cs (including the GUI).**

I can successfully do this:
- Create a C# Windows Forms project
- Create a F# Library project
- Reference the F# Library DLL from my C# project
- That way I can call F# functions from C#

But I still can't see my buttons and textboxes from F#
I understand that that is because it's a library and it can't reference System.Windows.Forms

So how do I fix this? I don't want it to be a library or this or that, I just want it to be a file that will allow me to write F# code while being able to reference my C# Form and code.
I guess you can say I want an F# file that is also a "partial class Form1" so that I can continue writing code for the same Project, but using F# instead.
How do I do that?

Comment: Have you declare Form1, Button or function in F# as public yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're actually asking how to structure your application so that you can use WinForms designer (which is only available in C#/VB) to create a form and at the same time, write the application logic in F#.

First of all, there is no way to mix the two languages in a single project, which means that you cannot write something like a `partial` class with one part in F# and other part in C# (this is technically *almost* impossible). So, the only option is to write an F# project and a C# project and reference one from the other. There are two ways to do this:

*(Based on your answer and comments, I think you may prefer the first one)*

**Referencing C# library from F# application:** One option is to create a simple WinForms library project in C# to contain the form (and possibly other controls etc.) created using the WinForms designer and nothing else. Then you'd reference this library from an application created in F# and implement all the user interaction in the F# application.

If you make sure to mark the `YourForm` class created by WinForms designer as well as all relevant controls added to the form as `public`, then you can reference the form and control it from your F# application.

- I used this approach in the one sample in my book, so if you're looking for an example, you can look at the [source code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp) for Chapter 14 (look for "FSharpEffects")

**Referencing F# library from C# application:** When you structure your application in this way, you'll need to create an F# library that exposes all the basic functionality that your application needs and then reference it from a C# application. The C# application would add all the user-interface interaction code and it would call the F# library to preform the actual work.

In this scenario, the F# library doesn't know anything about the C# form. If you reference *System.Windows.Forms* from your F# library then it may take some WinForms controls as arguments (e.g. to configure them & load data), but it won't know anything about the controls declared in C#.

One possible extension to this approach is to declare an interface in the F# library, implement it in the C# application and then pass an implementation back to the F# library. The interface may expose some important properties of the application (e.g. give access to all the important WinForms controls). Once you give an implementation of the interface to your F# library, the F# library can use it to manipulate with the application.

*(The approach with interface requires writing more code and may be less flexible, but if you want to write the main application in C# and declare the form there, it is probably the best option)*

Comment: First, I just bought your book yesterday and I like it a lot.
Second, thank you and Manning for the free pdf copy after buying the paper version.
I don't have .Net 4 yet so I can't compile your Chapter 14.
In the meantime your reply is clear and detailed enough to answer my question.
It's unfortunate that a class part C# and part F# is almost impossible. That's the kind of benefit that a Common Language Infrastructure should give us.
Seeing that both C# and F# compile to the same Intermediate Language, I'd expect this not only to be possible but a given.

Comment: @Pessimist, in that case, I suggest you change your username ;)

Comment: @Benjol: thanks for making me laugh :)
I'm a pessimist not because I expect the worse (that's the "street" definition, glass half empty, etc, not real philosophy), but because I think that what exists now is bad. I'd say that's in line with what we just found out about C# and F#. ;)

Comment: @Pessimist - Since you can't have a partial class shared between multiple C# projects, I don't know why it would be a given that you could share a partial class between a C# and an F# project. I agree that it will be nice when F# projects have a better UI story (Silverlight, I'm looking at you) but let's not assume miracles here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` to the F# project, and set the visibility of the `Form1` class and its members to `public`.

(Libraries can also reference System.Windows.Forms; that's what reusable control projects are)

You'll also need some way to call the F# code in the first place; you might want to make the F# project an EXE (that calls `Application.Run`) and the C# project into a library.

Comment: Okay I added the reference to that dll by going to Add reference > .Net > System.Windows.Forms.
Now I can do this on my F# file: open System.Windows.Forms
Now how do I reference my Form1 functions and buttons etc?

Comment: Your F# code needs an instance of the `Form1` class.  You might want to inherit it.

Comment: I don't want to have the F# code being the executable and then C# being a library because the whole project is already in C#. I really just want to write F# code for the existing project and its controls and functions, which are all in C#.

Comment: Yes, but the C# project will need to give an instance to the F# code.  The simplest way to do it is to keep all your code in C#, but invoke it from F#, supplying an inherited `Form1` instance.  Otherwise, you'd have a circular reference.

Comment: I'm not an OO guru but I don't see how inheriting would help. Can't I implement my F# code as being a partial class of Form1? Google says F# doesn't support partial classes but I don't know how outdated that is.

Comment: That is completely impossible (partial classes are merged at compile-time). You need to learn basic OO concepts.

Comment: Well if I inherit my Form1 on my F# file wouldn't I be creating a new instance of the Form1 instead of adding code to it? I thought inheriting only went down, not up.

Comment: Yes; you need to run that inherited class instead of the original.  Alternatively, you can pass the original instance of `Form1` to the F# project.

Comment: Then it's not what I want to do. And you need to read up on criticisms of OOP. It's not the best paradigm for every problem (probably not for any). I'll give this a try but what I really wanted is kind of the opposite of inheriting (which in OOP parlance would be a partial class, but in normal speak would be simply "a file that can see my other files").