# GUI programming with F#

Tags: user-interface, f#

I am looking at doing UI development with F#. I have experience using F# as a back end with C# and XAML as the front end, and have tried using the XAML type provider. I know of RX but haven't used it yet.

Does anyone know of other ways that you can do GUI programming in F#? Approaches that did not exist when these questions ["Is Functional GUI programming possible?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2672791/3382930) and [How to learn GUI programming in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2796272/3382930) were asked?

Details any pros/cons of an approach that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've done this before and was able to do what you describe in your first sentence, by simply referencing an F# project with all of the logic from the C# project with all of the graphics. Since it was a simple app, though, the F# side turned out to be pretty small.

Comment: https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/fsharp-wpf-mvc-series

Comment: I am interested in doing UI development with F#. I know a couple of techniques, I've read of a few more. 1) I want to know what else is out there 2) Outside of trying them all how can I find out about the pro's and cons of each. How do I word this question in a way that would be acceptable to the moderators?